# bluetoothctl write on descriptor to enable notification

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm having trouble on enabling notification of Bluetooth Low Energy Device, using bluetoothctl I'm able to connect to the device, however in gatttool i can't, It says connection refused (111). So I'm going the bluetoothctl direction. But I can't find a way to write to the descriptor to enable the notification and receive data from the device.

bluez version : 5.45
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any ideas?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have established the connection, in bluetoothctl select the characteristics attribute to which you want to enable the notification using "select-attribute" after this you can enable notification using "acquire-notify"

Comment: after selecting attribute, then acquire-notify , i get an error : Failed to acquire notify: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod. Using notify on, it has no error, but doesn't send notifications. 

From this tutorial, I see that using gatttool, the author was able to turn on the notifications http://blog.firszt.eu/index.php?post/2015/09/13/bt 
by using command char-write-cmd

Comment: After notify on make sure there is a change in the characteristics value to be notified, if notify on is not throwing any error it would have enabled the notification as far as I understand. Please see if the write request sent after notify on is properly acknowledged.